# cannot read property 'map of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, map-function

I am getting this error :

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined new
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:87221:34
>   ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:31251:30
>   ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:31247:21
>   ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:31231:25
>   Object.mountComponent
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:30937:39
>   Object.updateChildren
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:32163:69
>   Constructor._reconcilerUpdateChildren
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:32271:119
>   Constructor._updateChildren
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:32308:33
>   Constructor.updateChildren
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:32302:14
>   Constructor.receiveComponent
>       index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false:32375:119

main.js

```
 import icons from './icons'       

  type Cell = {
      image: any,
      animation: any
    };

    export default class Camera extends React.Component {
      cells: Cell[];
      background = new Animated.Value(HIDDEN);
      text = new Animated.Value(HIDDEN);
      state: { focused?: Cell } = {};

      constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.cells = icons.map((icon) => ({
          ...icon, animation: new Animated.Value(HIDDEN)
        }));


      }
```

icons.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons'
import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons'

const icons =[
  { name: 'Notes', image: <Icon name='device-camera' />},
  { name: 'Earth', image: <SimpleLineIcons name='camera' /> }
]

export { icons }
```

Comment: Did you log `icons`, looks like it's `undefined`

Comment: @adeneo yea, its showing undefined, don't know why ?

Comment: Then `import icons from './icons'` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @adeneo or maybe export { icons } not working  , don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Neither do I, or anyone else for that matter, if the issue is that `icons` isn't imported properly ?

Comment: @adeneo no solution then :(

Comment: Well, no? Either the path is wrong, or the export isn't working ?

Answer (score 3):

`export default icons;` within `icons.js` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that yesterday but didnt worked and tried it today again, it starts working. This is JS , no one knows what happens and why !!

Comment: Haha. You've gotta love JS and it's quirks :P